# C printf string specifier \t1?

Tags: c, string, format-specifiers

I am reading a piece of C heap sorting code and encounter this:

```
 do{
    printf("\n\t\t1:INSERT\n");
    printf("\n\t\t2:SEARCH\n");
    printf("\n\t\t3:DELETE\n");
    printf("\n\t\t1:DISPLAY\n");
    printf("Enter your choise\n");
    scanf("%d",&choise);
    switch(choise)
    {
        case 1: printf("Enter value to insert\n");
                scanf("%d",&val);
                last=insert(root,val);
                break;
        case 2:printf("Enter value for search \n");
                scanf("%d",&val);
                search(root,val);
                break;
        case 3:delete(root);
                delete(last);
                break;
        case 4:printf("\n\tHEAP\n");
                display(root);
                break;
        default : printf("INVALID choise ... can't you see properly?\n");

    }
```

Anyone knows whats `\t1` and `\t2` in the `printf`s and how do they work? I tried google but did not get any useful information.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\t` denotes a tab character.  The `1` and `2` are nothing to do with it; they are just  literal `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any mention of `\t` in any `printf` documentation because it has nothing to do with `printf`.  It's part of the syntax of a string literal, similar to the `\n` that precedes it.  `\n` denotes a new-line character; `\t` denotes a tab character.  `printf` never even sees the `'\'` characters, which are replaced at compile time; it just sees the new-line and tab characters, which it treats like any other ordinary characters that aren't part of any `%...` sequence.  (There may be some special treatment of these particular characters, but that's done by lower-level routines that are called by `printf`.)

And `\t1` denotes a tab character followed by a digit `1`.

(An aside: Unix-like systems have a [`printf` *command*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf), used from a shell prompt, that behaves similarly to the C `printf` function.  It does handle `\` sequences itself.)

Answer (score 0):

The specifiers are just `\t`, which is the tab character. The numbers are part of the literals printed.

Answer (score 0):

`\t` is just used to print a horizontal tab. The numbers will be printed as they are, and are not part of the `\t`. I.e:

```
printf("\n\t\t1:INSERT\n");
printf("\n\t\t2:SEARCH\n");
printf("\n\t\t3:DELETE\n");
printf("\n\t\t1:DISPLAY\n");
printf("Enter your choise\n");
```

will print something like:

```
    1:INSERT

    2:SEARCH

    3:DELETE

    1:DISPLAY
Enter your choise
```

Answer (score 0):

`\t` is tab. It prints tab character and then you print `1`. Its like doing `/n1`. It means leave a line and then print `1`.

```
\t  -----> I am a tab character that prints spaces.

1   -----> I am a number.
```

We both are **not** a single character.

```
\t1 -----> Print tab character and then print 1. 

\t2 -----> Print tab character and then print 2.
```

Get that now?